# Object variable or with block variable not set - Error

Tags: vba, excel

I was running a simple VBA code as below:

```
Sub TransferData()

'transfer stuff from workbook 1 to workbook 2

    Dim strPath1 As String

    Dim strPath2 As String

    Dim wbkWorkbook1 As Workbook

    Dim wbkWorkbook2 As Workbook

    'define paths and filenames

    strPath1 = "C:\blp\data\grid1.xls"

    strPath2 = "Z:\24AM\Risk Managemen\Risk Management Processes.xlsm"

    'copy the values across

    wbkWorkbook2.Worksheets("FXDUMP").Range("A1:Z2000").Value = wbkWorkbook1.Worksheets("Book1").Range("A1:Z2000").Value

    'close the two workbooks

    wbkWorkbook1.Close (False)

    wbkWorkbook2.Close (True)
End Sub
```

But when I try to run the macro, I got this error message:

> Object variable or with block variable not set

Can you please give me an input to figure out this issue?

Thank in advance.

Comment: You haven't assigned anything to either workbook variable.

Comment: Your workbook variables haven't been assigned...

Answer (score 1):

Include the below statements in your code, It will open the excel sheet and assign the variables to  excel sheet

```
Set wbkWorkbook1 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=strPath1)
Set wbkWorkbook2 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=strPath2)
```